# How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{A}{B + Cx} - Dx\right) dx$?

Tags: integration, special-functions

How to evaluate the integral (or at least rewrite it in some form of special function)

$$\int_0^\infty  \exp \left(-\frac{A}{B + Cx} - Dx\right) dx$$

where $A,B,C,D > 0$ ?

Also is this task even possible for the easy case $A = B = C = D = 1$ ?

Comment: What does $\int (f(x)-dx)\,dx$ mean?

Comment: @lulu pretty sure $d$ is another constant here.. I'm going to change these to capital letters.

Comment: @CameronWilliams  Oh, I bet you are right.  Maybe not the best notation.

Comment: Yeah I had the same thought. Nearly had a conniption. :D

Comment: OP: look at my rewrite of your $\rm\LaTeX$. You'll see that I removed a bunch of extra brackets. They are unnecessary.

Comment: Oh my god I am so sorry that the presentation goes wrong like this ! The correction offer by user Cameron Williams is correct !

Comment: For $B=0$ the integral can be expressed in terms of Macdonald function.

Comment: Since the integral has a maximum at $\sqrt{AC/D} -B$, numerical methods maybe very accurate here; possible this can produce some asymptotics in terms and the parameters $A$, $B$, etc as in Laplace's method.